# Calling a method on a nil struct pointer doesn't panic. Why not?

Tags: go, struct

```
type MyError struct {
    errors []string
}

func (t *MyError) Error() string {
    if t == nil {
        fmt.Println("t ptr empty")
        return ""
    }
    pointers := make([]string, 0, len(t.errors))
    for i, r := range t.errors {
        pointers[i] = r
    }
    sort.Strings(pointers)
    return fmt.Sprintf("n error(s) decoding:\n\n%s", len(t.errors), strings.Join(pointers, ","))
}

func main() {
    var err *MyError
    err.Error()  // expected "panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference" here
}
```

The variable err is nil so calling err.Error() method is expected to cause a panic "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference", but the method call succeeds. Why doesn't this panic?

Comment: Because the language spec says so?

Answer (score 31):

[Michael Jones explained this well](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/wcrZ3P1zeAk/WI88iQgFMvwJ) (copied as answer):

> In Go the function to be called by the Expression.Name() syntax is
>   entirely determined by the type of Expression and not by the
>   particular run-time value of that expression, including nil.
>
> In this manner, the invocation of a method on a nil pointer of a
>   specific type has a clear and logical meaning.
>
> Those familiar with vtable[] implementations will find this odd at
>   first, yet, when thinking of methods this way, it is even simpler and
>   makes sense. Think of:
>
> ```
> func (p *Sometype) Somemethod (firstArg int) {}
> ```
>
> as having the literal meaning:
>
> ```
> func SometypeSomemethod(p *Sometype, firstArg int) {}
> ```
>
> and in this view, the body of SometypeSomemethod() is certainly free
>   to test it's (actual) first argument (p *Sometype) for a value of nil.

Answer (score 9):

Please read: https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value

> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings,
>   and **nil for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and
>   maps**. This initialization is done recursively, so for instance each
>   element of an array of structs will have its fields zeroed if no value
>   is specified.

So in your code, `var err *MyError` is `nil`, you can call `err.Error()` is ok even `err = nill`,

**

> In Go, the function to be called by the Expression.Name() syntax is
>   entirely determined by the type of Expression and not by the
>   particular run-time value of that expression, including nil.

**

Answer (score 0):

Coming from C++/Java, this can look odd, another gotcha is that an interface holding a nil struct is not itself nil!

You can try this on go playground to get a hang of things:

```
type inf interface {
  test() string
}

type s struct {
}

func (t *s) test() string {
   return "nil struct with pointer reciever can still call method\n"
}

func main() {
    var sTest *s
    if sTest == nil {
       fmt.Printf("sTest is Nil\n")
    }
    
    fmt.Printf("%s", sTest.test())
    
    var fTest inf
    if fTest == nil {
       fmt.Printf("fTest is nil\n")
    }
    
        fTest = sTest
        if fTest != nil {
           fmt.Printf("interface holding nil is not nil!\n")
        }
}
```

The key thing to you: go 'inheritance' is actually *duck typing.* And interfaces are defined to be able hold any valid value, and nil itself is a valid value!